# Php array conversion processing？

Tags: php, arrays

array A: `array('name','world cup','lang','ru');`
array B: `array('name'=>'world cup','lang'=>'ru');`
How to convert array A into arrayB in the best way?

Comment: It’s so smart, but what if I have two elements in my array?

Comment: just use for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a for-loop and generate the array.

While generating you need check if the next item is defined before adding it to array B.

```
$arrayA = array('name','world cup','lang','ru');

for($i=0; $i < count($arrayA); $i+=2){
    $arrayB[$arrayA[$i]] = isset($arrayA[$i+1]) ? $arrayA[$i+1] : '';
}

print_r($arrayB);
```

Comment: since you're incrementing by two's you can just use isset alone, its understood that if `+1` isn't set it means its the array is jagged (missing pair), no need for modulus, something like `for` loop and a simple ternary `$arrayB[$arrayA[$i]] = isset($arrayA[$i+1])? $arrayA[$i+1] : '';`

Answer (score 1):

If you have arrays of varying sizes, and it's always in the order of `key, value, key, value, ...` you can make a function that converts it:

```
/**
 * Converts numeric array to key - value pairs in order
 *
 * @param array $arrayA
 * @return array $arrayB
 */
function convertArrays($arrayA)
{
    $keys = array(); //array to store keys
    $values = array(); //array to store values

    //seperate keys and values
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayA); $i++)
    {
        if($i % 2 == 0) //is even number
        {
            array_push($keys, $arrayA[$i]); //add to keys array
        }
        else //is odd number
        {
            array_push($values, $arrayA[$i]; //add to values array
        }
    }

    $arrayB = array(); //array for combined key/value pairs

    $max = count($keys);
    if(count($keys) != count($values)) //original array wasn’t even
    {
        $max = count($keys) - 1;
    }

    //join into single array
    for($j = 0; $j < $max; $j++)
    {
        $arrayB[ $keys[$j] ] = $values[$j];
    }

    return $arrayB;
}
```

Comment: What if you get array A not divisible by 2? This answer is buggy.

Comment: That’s what I said at the bottom. Only works if the array is always even. If the asker wants to modify it to check for all possibilities he/she can. This is just an example of how the code might look.

Answer (score -1):

if the format remains constant and you wont get more  pairs:

```
$arrayA=array('name','world cup','lang','ru');
$arrayB=array($arrayA[0]=>$arrayA[1],$arrayA[2]=>$arrayA[3]);

print_r($arrayB);



Array
(
    [name] => world cup
    [lang] => ru
```

)